# Can TypeScript understand Svelte components?

Tags: typescript, svelte

Svelte ultimately outputs native JavaScript classes. So, TypeScript could understand these. However, Svelte components have to first be compiled from their initial `.html` form. Until then, understandably, TypeScript by default does not understand them in their initial form. So, it reports a 'cannot find module' error, even though at runtime the import is successful. Is there any way to make TypeScript understand them?

One workaround would be to provide type definitions for `.html` modules, approximating the standard Svelte component interface. However, it would be much more desirable to simply use the real component class output itself for each individual component, yielding the most accurate type information.

As an aside, I have not mentioned tools like Webpack or Rollup which perform the compilation step for Svelte normally. I do not know whether these tools would be relevant to this question.

**Update 1:** I've looked a little further into TypeScript and it [seems that plugins can be created for it](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Writing-a-Language-Service-Plugin). However, they seem limited, so may not be useful.

**Update 2:** There has also been some talk ([here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11610) and [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3136)) about custom module loaders in TypeScript.

Answer (score 18):

**Yes**. Use [rollup-plugin-svelte](https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-svelte) and [rollup-plugin-typescript](https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-typescript) and it should work. I am using it in a rollup file now that looks as follows:

```
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs'
import replace from 'rollup-plugin-replace'
import resolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve'
import svelte from 'rollup-plugin-svelte'
import typescript from 'rollup-plugin-typescript'

const path = require('path')
const fs = require('fs')

export default {
  input: 'src/index.ts',
  plugins: [
    typescript(),
    commonjs({
      include: 'node_modules/**'
    }),
    resolve({
      browser: true,
      preferBuiltins: false // for url npm module; otherwise rollup assumes node
    }),
    // Replace is to shut up redux
    replace({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV)
    }),
    svelte({
      // By default, all .html and .svelte files are compiled
      extensions: ['.my-custom-extension', '.html', '.svelte'],

      // You can restrict which files are compiled
      // using `include` and `exclude`
      // include: 'src/components/**/*.html',

      // By default, the client-side compiler is used. You
      // can also use the server-side rendering compiler
      // generate: 'ssr',

      // Extract CSS into a separate file (recommended).
      css: function (css) {
        fs.writeFileSync('./dist/svelte.css', css)
      }
    })
  ],
  output: {
    format: 'iife',
    file: path.join(__dirname, './dist/index_dist.js') // equivalent to --output
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. With this approach, you receive no errors in the TypeScript compiler? I attempted something similar with Webpack, but then realised that the output is to a single file and is therefore invisible to the TypeScript compiler. The problem remains that we are importing a HTML file which always remains a HTML file, which TypeScript always doesn't understand (besides static type definitions).

Comment: I do not have any errors. A couple of factors here - Remember that the way that svelte works is it turns the HTML into pure JavaScript (after a rollup compile look through the output js file and find the components). Rollupjs, which I'm using instead of webpack happens to also have been originally authored by the same dev that authored Svelte, so I suspect that makes some things go more smoothly than webpack. Once I found rollup though, I never went back to webpack for months or maybe a year now.

Comment: I imagine Webpack is also capable of it with the right configuration. However, I don't see how a build tool would help an IDE with its TypeScript integration. IDEs usually run their own TypeScript compiler. These compilers will still not know how to handle a `.html` file, and will have no knowledge of the output of any build tool (unless you outputted each compiled component next to its template, but that could get messy quite quickly).

Comment: When you say "help an IDE", I suppose you mean intellisense and linting. First, I don't pay much attention to that. I keep the code in my HTML files super small and mostly calling out to external scripts. So there is little-to-no TypeScript-specific syntax. However, linters work in VSCode because you can configure them however you want with the workspace settings. In any case, the final compiler/output settings are unrelated.

Comment: Yes, IDE integration of TypeScript, which makes TS errors much more approachable than reading a compiler console. My original question is not about placing TS into the <script> of a Svelte component, but about being able to import compiled Svelte components into those external scripts you mention and use those Svelte classes as types. The most obvious benefit to this would be TS knowing that a Svelte component has some methods on it, and these methods appearing and not displaying errors in the IDE integration. It would also be possible to use operators like `component instanceof Component`.

Comment: I should note that you can of course use `component instanceof Component` at _runtime_, but the trouble remains that the TypeScript IDE integration does not understand `Component` at its _compile_ time.

Comment: TypeScript requires type definitions for that and the svelte compiler does not emit them. IMHO components in the view should have very little logic and very few methods on them. My components tend to only observe redux state and invoke actions so there so I almost never call a method on a component. So I have not found this to be a need.

Comment: That's not true actually. TypeScript can extract implicit typing from any object, class, method, or other JavaScript code. Implicit typing tends not to paint the complete picture, but part of it. This would include exposed methods on a Svelte component which are a standard part of Svelte and are used by many users.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisTalman I don't think I'm being very helpful to you despite my efforts :) Let me know if there is some way that I can be helpful.

Comment: No worries. From what I understand it seems like some sort of TypeScript plugin or loader would probably be best suited to address this issue. There have been similar discussions about other template languages and interaction with them from a TypeScript script in the context of an IDE. However, it's not clear whether the TypeScript language has the facility for this yet. Given that Svelte is written in TypeScript, I imagine the contributors may eventually address this issue, but in the grand scheme of things it's a relatively minor issue.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**. Svelte has official support for typescript!
https://svelte.dev/blog/svelte-and-typescript

When starting a project
with [Vite](http://vitejs.dev) `npm create vite@latest`
*or* [SvelteKit](https://kit.svelte.dev) `npm create svelte@latest`
Choose the **TypeScript** option.

The Svelte ESLint also works with TypeScript, see the [Readme](https://github.com/sveltejs/eslint-plugin-svelte3#installation-with-typescript) for more info.